# Is it normal for a conference to let the submissions modifiable long after the deadline?

Tags: peer-review, conference

Is it normal for a conference to let the submissions be editable on easychair website by the authors (and still be able to submit new papers) after 3 weeks of the hard deadline and only one week before the notification of acceptence? I thought they will disable these options once they assign the reviewers.

Comment: Are you a submitter or reviewer?

Comment: I am a submitter (to a scientific conference).

Comment: Are you just curious, or wondering if you should hold off on editing?

Comment: Well, I think it is ok to be able to edit a submission during (say) the first week after the deadline, but now after 3 weeks (and still), I started to wonder if that is normal?

Comment: In CS, the PLoP conferences actually require it, since the review process is open and the authors work with a "shepherd" (a bit different from a reviewer) to improve the paper before the acceptance/rejection decision. I doubt that is what you mean, though.

Comment: @Buffy Oh, I see, but isn't that cause a conflict with the reviewers who have already started reviewing the manuscript while the author may still edit it for changes?

Comment: Not for these conferences. The normal "review" is replaced by "shepherding", not in addition to it. Ultimately the shepherd makes a recommendation to the chair. Most papers get improved substantially. I've had to recommend rejection only once and acceptance many times. In my rejection, it was because the authors refused to correct a fundamental error and repeatedly let it stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal.

EasyChair has many options that can be set by conference organizers. In principle, this is a good thing, since it allows the program chairs to configure their conference management system exactly as they want to. However, it also means that it is relatively easy to make mistakes in the EasyChair settings. I think the program chairs may simply be making a mistake right now, and they may not be aware that submissions can still be added/modified.